# Solutions to ODE with singularities which are removable conditional on specific starting values

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, singularity

I want to understand the solutions to ODE with removable discontinuities (conditional on specific starting values). For example, I have the function $y(x)$ defined by:
\begin{align*}
\sin(x) = \sin(2 y)  \text{ for } x \in [0, \pi], y \in [0, 1/2 \pi]. 
\end{align*}
It gives me the following differential equation:
\begin{align*}
y'(x) = \frac{\sin'(x)}{2 \sin'(2y(x))},  \quad y(0) = 0;
\end{align*}
where $\sin'(x) = \cos(x)$. There is a singularity at $y=\pi/2$. However, ***on the optimal path*** starting from $y(0)=0$, this singularity will be **removable**. Indeed, on $[0, \pi/2[$, we find that $y^*(x)= x/2$. Thus:
\begin{align*}
lim_{x\rightarrow\pi/2} \ y'(x) = \frac{\cos(\pi/2)}{2\cos(\pi/2) } = 1/2. 
\end{align*}

This is **not exactly a "removable singular point"**, but ***conditional* on being on this specific path**, with this specific starting value, the **discontinuity is not a discontinuity anymore**. **Is there a name for this?**

Now, it seems there are **two solutions** to this equation (maybe I'm wrong and there are more?):
\begin{align*}
y_1(x) = x/2 \text{ for } x \in [0, \pi]
\end{align*}
or:
\begin{align*}
y_2(x) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        x/2 & \mbox{for } x \in [0, \pi/2] \\
        \pi/2-x/2 & \mbox{for } x \in [\pi/2, \pi]. \\
    \end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}

In other words, once you reach the singularity, you can either go backwards, or upwards. But I found these solutions naturally by thinking, not with equations/maths.
Moreover, I don't know **how to prove that these are the only two solutions**, and I'd like to prove it.

I think this property holds more generally, even in higher dimension, i.e. if I have **isolated singular points**, if I reach a singularity that is *removable given the optimal path*, I still have two (in 2D case, more in higher dimensions) solutions/directions that I can choose (*at least locally*) for the solution.
**How can I prove this? Is there any known results?**

It is particularly important because it would imply that there exists a **unique strictly increasing solution** to these kind of problems.